# QColor into list for later retrieval

Tags: qt, qcolor

I want to add all the selected colors into a list without duplicate entry and later all the selected colors should popup in a widget.

How can I add QColor into list and later extract it

Comment: Use `QSet` instead of `QList`

Comment: @DmitrySazonov, `QSet` doesn't guarantee its items uniqueness.

Comment: QSet not working for QColor

Comment: @vahancho wow. This is new for me. Question is why?

Comment: @DmitrySazonov, ops, sorry, I am wrong - it doesn't allow duplicates. However it's not sorted as `std::set`.

Comment: QSet doesn't allow duplicates, you just can't use it with QColor. You need to use QList and do the check

Comment: Could you please show your code and explain what is your problem?

Comment: @vahancho `QSet` is unordered because it based on `QHash`. `std::set` is based on `std::map`-like tree, thats why it is sorted. Anyway, i think that in current context it is better to use `QList` with removing dublicates. Possible, author wants some predicted order for elements.

Comment: Your problem description is absolutely lacking; still haven't read and understood [ask] and [mcve]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QColor` does not provide a hash function for `QSet` or `std::unordered_set` by default. You can add that locally (or globally for your program) though by delegating that to the hash function for QRgb (which includes alpha value as well):

```
#include <QColor>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QSet>

#include <unordered_set>

// hash function for QColor for use in QSet / QHash
QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
uint qHash(const QColor &c)
{
    return qHash(c.rgba());
}
QT_END_NAMESPACE

// hash function for QColor for std::unordered_set
namespace std {
template<> struct hash<QColor>
{
    using argument_type = QColor;
    using result_type = size_t;
    result_type operator()(const argument_type &c) const
    {
        return hash<QRgb>()(c.rgba());
    }
};
} // namespace std


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QSet<QColor> qs;
    qs.insert(QColor(100, 100, 100));
    qs.insert(QColor(100, 100, 100));
    qs.insert(QColor(50, 100, 100));
    qDebug() << qs.size() << qs.toList();

    std::unordered_set<QColor> ss;
    ss.insert(QColor(100, 100, 100));
    ss.insert(QColor(100, 100, 100));
    ss.insert(QColor(50, 100, 100));
    qDebug() << ss.size();
    for (auto c : ss)
        qDebug() << c;

    return 0;
}
```

Or you can also not put the `QColor`s into the set, but the `QRgb` values (via `QColor::rgba()`), and later convert them back to `QColor` via the `QColor(QRgb)` constructor again.